# Sens de l'adjectif « convenu » dans « indignation convenue » en contexte ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

> La problématique de la gériatrie recoupe celle des urgences. Aucun
> politique n’a trouvé de solutions aux problèmes connus depuis des
> lustres et c’est une source récurrente d’**indignation convenue** ne
> débouchant sur aucun changement. Les malades de gériatrie sont devenus
> un des « boulets » des services d’urgence, au même titre que les
> malades de psychiatrie ou les SDF dont on se défait plus facilement.
>
> [ *Le cataclysme du Covid-19 doit servir de catalyseur pour redéfinir
> notre politique du grand âge*, sur [Lemonde.fr](https://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2020/05/25/le-cataclysme-du-covid-19-doit-servir-de-catalyseur-pour-redefinir-notre-politique-du-grand-age_6040703_3232.html) ]

De quel sens de l'adjectif [*convenu*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/convenu/1) s'agit-il ici : s'agit-il de ce qui est fait par *convention* ou d'un emploi péjoratif et dans ce cas comment savoir s'il s'agit d'un manque d'originalité ou de sincérité et pourquoi ; ce syntagme est-il figé ?

Comment: Pistes de traduction en anglais : https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63389413#63389413

Answer (score 4):

Il s'agit clairement du sens *B* du TLFi :

> Par extension, péjoratif. Qui ne correspond pas à la réalité; qui manque de sincérité ou d'originalité; qui est factice, de pure forme.

Dans le cas de l'article, ce n'est pas de l'originalité qu'il s'agit mais du manque de sincérité, ou plutôt du manque d'implication. L'impuissance, l'inaction qui en découle est bien ce qui est reproché aux politiques.

Cette indignation convenue est donc une indignation de circonstance, de façade.

On trouve suffisamment d'indignations convenues pour considérer qu'il s'agit d'une forme figée, ou du moins d'une collocation fréquente.

Par exemple :

> Loin de l’indignation convenue, des « plus jamais ça » proférés avec emphase par des politiques impuissants,  Maylis de Kerangal, avec ce texte court à l’écriture précise, subtile, presque douce, offre un linceul de mots et sauve de l’oubli ces naufragés à jamais disparus dans la transparence bleutée de la Méditerranée et l’indifférence des hommes.
> Jean-Marc Savoye [Onlalu](https://www.onlalu.com/livres/roman-francais/a-ce-stade-de-la-nuit-maylis-de-kerangal-7666/)

Comment: J'ai souvent employé l'adjectif comme dans ce contexte, mais en l'entendant comme *une indignation "dont tout le monde convient"*, comme si l'indignation est unanime et d'un commun accord. Est-ce correct ? Cela colle avec la définition III. A. 1. du (CNRTL)[https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/convenu], n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @Marck J'ai du mal à voir comment tout le monde pourrait se mettre d'accord pour s'indigner de quelque chose sans qu'il y ait le côté négatif du sens figuré qui colle bien mieux avec le paragraphe en question.

Comment: l'indignation commune signifie que toute les personnes sont du même avis, c'est alors une expression signifiant que, les avis des acteurs se rejoignant, ils ont en quelque sorte convenu que la situation était indignante.

Comment: @Marck  *Indignante ?* Une ***indignation commune*** est une indignation partagée et non feinte, une ***indignation convenue*** est une indignation de circonstance, de façade.

Comment: @Marck je crois aussi que _convenue_ ici signifie _de convenance_ (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/convenance, voir _mariage de convenance_).

Comment: @Frank oui en effet, c'est grandement possible !